# Remove multiple items from TStringList after compare

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Anyone can help what is the best way to compare two stringlist and get difference from them?

For example if I have AList and BList like

**AList**

- ABC
- CDE
- EFG
- KLM
- STA
- LMO
- TKJ

**BList**

- ABC
- CDE
- EFG
- KLM
- STA
- LMO
- TKJ
- FGJ
- FGJ
- ARE
- IJE

If I compare them like

```
     for i := 0 to BList.count-1 do
       if AList.indexof(BList[i]) < 0 then
         ResultList.Add(BList[i]);
```

Result is:

- FGJ
- FGJ
- ARE
- IJE

I need elements only once. How can I avoid multiple items? Is there a better solution than to make a procedure that remove multiple items from the List? Sorry for my English and thanks for the help!

Comment: It looks like you already have your solution - just add another check `if ResultList.indexof(BList[i]) < 0 then`

Comment: How long your lists are? Are you aware about algorithm speed?

Comment: I fill both of the Lists from Database so the length will be variable. From 200 to 5000+ record. Yeah, I am afraid of. Why?

Comment: If this operation is frequent, it would be wise to care about algorithmic effectiveness, make one list sorted, and search with Find instead of IndexOf. Complexity O(NlogN) against current O(N^2)

Comment: Your database query can do all of this

Comment: @MBo n log n can easily be bettered. You can do it with a single linear pass over the arrays.

Comment: @David Heffernan Yes, if arrays are sorted.

Comment: @MBo sorting increase the expense for large data sets. Hashed O(1) lookup wins asymptotically. But if you are going to sort, don't do repeated binary searches.

Comment: @David Heffernan  OK, I forgot about hashing (though extra memory needed). Anyway, you are right that database engine should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The TStringList has a property `Duplicates` which controls what should happen when duplicates are attempted to be added to a **sorted** list.

From the documentation:

> **dupIgnore**   Ignore attempts to add duplicate strings to the list.
>
> **dupError**   raise an EStringListError exception when an attempt is made
>   to add duplicate strings to the sorted list.
>
> **dupAccept**    Permit duplicate strings in the sorted list.

So, set

```
  ResultList.Sorted := True;
  ResultList.Duplicates := dupIgnore;
```

Comment: FWIW, this is very inefficient for large data sets because of the overhead of maintaining a sorted list, and searching for duplicates on every addition to the list.